# Descendant selector (>) combined with root selector (&) resulting in wrong compilation

Tags: sass

The problem is very simple to explain.

This is the input:

```
.a {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 960px;
    background: #a3c1ef;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;

    > &-b {
        list-style: none;
        > &-c {
            display: inline-block;
            color: blue;
            font-size: 100px;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
.a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
  background: #a3c1ef;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.a > a-b {
  list-style: none;
}
.a > a-b > a-b-c {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

and this is the actual output I'm getting:

```
.a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
  background: #a3c1ef;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
> .a-b {
  list-style: none;
}
> > .a-b-c {
  display: inline-block;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

When I remove the root selector `&`, the output is as expected: `a > b > c`. But when I use the root selector `&` in combination with the direct descendant selector `>`, the output is the above. This behavior is so counter-intuitive. 
Can someone explain how to fix it (if it's possible)?

SASS compiler version: 1.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start by copying the parent selector ahead of the > and then dive through it. The third child however will be output as .a > .a-b > .a > .a-b-c {} so it is easier to step out a level and start again like in my example.

I have [created a sassmeister example for you](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/bf76185c482440fa90de7f5090b33d8b) based off of your example that should do the trick. Hope that helps.

[Other Tips on using the & that might help](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to be lazy. As I'm using SMACSS's naming convention, the selectors can get really long. I also misunderstood the working of the ampersand.